# Selecionar delegados C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity

Tengo Scriptable Objects con varias variables, y quiero almacenar acciones, he probado con delegados.
El problema es asignar un delegado en concreto a un Scriptable Object desde el inspector, para hacerlo tendría que hacer cada Scriptable Object de una clase distinta.
Aquí hay un fragmento de código para entender mejor mi problema:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Scriptable Objects", menuName = "Monstruo")]
public class DatMonstruo : ScriptableObject // Varias instancias de este scriptable object en unity editables desde el inspector
{
    // Otras variables
    public Func<> Accion;

    // Quiero seleccionar en el inspector la variable funcion que quiera sin

    public void Funcion1()
    {
        // Hacer algo
    }

    // Mas Funciones
}
```

También he probado a relacionar un enum con una lista de todas las funciones, pero es muy dificil de trabajar con eso

Comment: No entiendo el problema, puedes dar mas detalles?? además, te quedó una oración sin terminar en los comentarios: `Quiero seleccionar en el inspector la variable funcion que quiera sin ...???`

Comment: Perdón, quiero decir que necesito que al ver un Scriptable Object en el inspector, tenga un parámetro que guarde una funcion (algo como un delegado o otra cosa mas ingeniosa), y ahí pueda elegir que funcion hace esa instancia especifia del Scriptable Object